# How to know Content-length

Tags: http, http-headers

I want to be able to know the size of a remote file without downloading it. I know there are some solutions using the "Content-length" header value, but for some links this header is missing. In that case, a solution would be to download the whole file, but what happens if the file is bigger than 1Gb for example.

What is the way download managers use to find out the size of a remote file?

If you have any solution in any languages, I will take it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Content-length` is an optional header which specifies the length of the resource in an HTTP protocol.

Here are some details on it: [HTTP/1.1: Header Field Definitions - 14.13 Content-Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13)

Basically, this is notable part:

> Applications SHOULD use this field to indicate the transfer-length of
>   the message-body, unless this is prohibited by the rules in section
>   4.4.

And the section [4.4 Message Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) should help you too.

> I know there is some solutions using the "Content-length" header but
>   for few links it doesn't exist.

If the server does not send any kind of Content-Length, there is no way to know the size for sure (except special cases described in section 4.4). Therefore, download manager will **not know** the length beforehand, and **will** download everything it gets until server stops giving it data.